# How to tune dense_rank() analytical function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, dense-rank

The `dense_rank()` function is taking 20 sec to fetch results.

How can I **tune** it to take less than **2-3 sec**? Alternatively, how can I achieve the below result without using `dense_rank()` function?

Table `meter_read_alert` is interval partitioned based on `read_time` column .
Every day around **10M** reads are getting inserted into the table.

Below is my code:

```
select   mfg_serial_num, device_id, channel_id, read_value, read_time
 ,nvl(read_value - Lag(read_value, 1) over ( ORDER BY read_time),0) as reading_monthwise,
Val_status
 from (
select mfg_serial_num, device_id, channel_id, read_value, read_time,Val_status,
Dense_rank() over ( PARTITION BY channel_id,to_char ( read_time, 'mm/yy') ORDER BY read_time)   AS up_rnk ,
Dense_rank() over ( PARTITION BY channel_id,to_char ( read_time, 'mm/yy') ORDER BY read_time desc)  AS down_rnk
        from eip.Meter_Read_Alert
        where READ_TIME between To_Date('01-06-2020 12:00:00 AM' ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss AM') 
        and To_Date('31-12-2020 11:59:00 PM' ,'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss AM')
        and  MFG_SERIAL_NUM='310821207'
)where up_rnk=1 OR down_rnk=1
```

[image]

For each mfg_serial_num, there are max 24 reads per day.
Below table has only 4.7K rows for mfg_serial_num=310387596 and given date range.

[image]

explain plan for the query:
[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
06-01-2021 : I have created a composite index on mfg_serial_num, read_time column and updated the stats of the table. Still the query is using old index. Tried using index hint, but its taking even more time.

Comment: What is the query plan?  What indexes are available?  In particular, is there a local index on `mfg_serial_num`?  is `mfg_serial_num` a number?  Or a string?

Comment: @JustinCave  MfG_serial_num is a string. Explain plan for the query  and index details is attached. Could you help me on how to know if an index is local or global ?

Comment: What is the definition of the index `to_char_read_time`?  Are there other indexes available?  If there isn't an index on (`read_time`, `mfg_serial_num`), that would probably be beneficial.

Comment: Not about performance, but your query can return unstable results, because you do not specify ordering or partitioning on `device_id, channel_id`, so `lag`'s value can vary depending on what will return your subquery.

Comment: If `channel_id, mfg_serial_num, read_time` is the key, then you can consider replacing of `dense_rank()` and filtering with `min(read_value) keep(dense_rank first order by read_time asc)` (and the same for desc) and group by `trunc(read_time, 'mm')`.

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: @JustinCave to_char_read_time is funcntion based index.  Index is already created on  read_time, mfg_serial_num columns as mfg_sno_all_idx , readtime_all_idx respectively.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  every meter (mfg_serial_num) has 24 reads per day.. I am trying to calculate monthly consumption .by taking the difference on 12 AM read of  first day of a month  and 11PM read of last day of a month. For example 30-06-2020 11PM read - 01-06-2020 12 AM read .   So i am using dense_rank() to fetch first and last read of every month and then using lag function to take difference of reads to calculate monthly consumption of a meter. Hope i am able to explain the logic here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  could you help me on this.